# Passing information to a function without using temporary variables in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba

I've seen instances of code where info is passed to a function without a temporary variable and I can't figure out how to do it.  Here is what I mean:

```
For i = 1 to ubound(arr)
    temp = cool_function(arr(i))
next
```

So in the above it's possible to pass arr(i) directly to the cool_function.  However, when I try that I get a ByRef argument type mismatch.  What I have to do instead is the following:

```
For i = 1 to ubound(arr)
    temp2 = arr(i)
    temp = cool_function(temp2)
next
```

I have to assign the value of arr(i) to temp2, then pass temp2 to the function.  How can I pass values to functions which are part of an array.  I tried putting ByVal in the function but that didn't work.

***************UPDATE***************
Problem solved.  It was the ByVal that was needed. I made a few typos but I was able to get it to work.

Comment: Show the definitions of `arr` and `cool_function`, the solution entirely depends on those.

Answer (score 1):

It should work as long as the element type is the same as the argument type.
So for example you have a function like this:

```
Function cool_function(wild As String)
    '~~> cool stuff here
End Function
```

In your sub, below should work:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim arr() As String
    '~~> populate array somewhere here
    For i = 1 to Ubound(arr)
        temp = cool_function(arr(i))
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Sub arrFunctionTest()

    Dim arrV(3) As Variant

    For i = 1 To 3
        arrV(i) = i
        arrV(i) = cool_Function(arrV, i)
    Next i

    For i = 1 To 3
        Debug.Print arrV(i)
    Next i

End Sub


Function cool_Function(arr As Variant, i) As Integer
    cool_Function = arr(i) * 2
End Function
```